# 'Move into next room' effect from one Div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a centered large div with an image in it, within that image is a doorway to the right.
I'm wanting to make it so that when you click the doorway, it 'zooms' to the next image, which will be of the next room.

The best way to describe it is similar to what Street View does when you're going down the road on Google maps.

Can anybody help?
Preferably jQuery, but I am open to anything.
Tried a few Zoom like plugins, but to no affect.

The ideal solution would be to go to another Div, so I am then able to control the content within the next 'room' (I have interactive objects in each 'room').

Hopefully this makes sense?

Example I'm working on: http://www.ether-game.com/new

Comment: You could lay the next div to the side of the current "room", and hide it. Then on click, show it and animate the two divs to move left x amount of pixels?

Comment: It would make a whole lot more sense if you could replicate your problem in jsfiddle, or at least post your problem code.

Comment: What code have you tried already?

Comment: Sorry @Lowkase , I wasn't sure whether I had permission to show what I'm doing, but then again, it's going to change a lot.

So this is the example: http://www.ether-game.com/new/

I've tried the current zoom code on there, which isn't what I want, and I've tried jQuery Zoombox. But it would be great if I could get it so that the current room blurs out as you zoom into the next room.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/F9vhD/

You just need to move one div to -100% left of its own width, and the other one the same.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="room" id="room1">
Room 1
<input type="button" id="nextRoom" value="go to next room" />
</div>
<div class="room" id="room2">
 s
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden
}

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#fff
}

.room {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0
}

#room1 {
    background:red;
}

#room2 {
    background: blue;
    left:100%
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nextRoom').on('click', function() {
            $('#room1').animate({left:'-100%'}); 
        $('#room2').animate({left:'0%'});
    });

});
```

Comment: Not quite, it's more an actual diving into the image motion.
Looking at the example with you give you the idea, thanks for the reply though:

http://www.ether-game.com/new/